# NestJs cannot create the module instance when importing pre-built library

Tags: nestjs

I created a new NestJs application (nest new project-name).
I then created a new Library (nest g library hello).
I then build the library I created (nest build hello).

After all of that, I imported the built library into my main module.

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AppController} from './app.controller';
import {AppService} from './app.service';
import {HelloModule} from '../libs/hello/hello-file.js';

@Module({
    imports: [HelloModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I get the following error:

> Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it.

If I import the ts module, everything works fine.

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AppController} from './app.controller';
import {AppService} from './app.service';
import {HelloModule} from '../libs/hello/src/hello.module';

@Module({
    imports: [HelloModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I need a way to import libraries as a js file (after building them).

Thanks

Comment: You should never import using file extensions with ES Modules.
Why would you want to specifically import a JS file?

Comment: I want to add compiled modules at run time.

Comment: If you need to load it conditionally, you should use Dynamic Imports. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

Though that won't work with Decorators, because they get invoked before you can call the import statement. For that, you can use Dynamic NestJS modules.

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules

Comment: Dynamic modules only allow passing config data into a module, not to load pre-compiled modules

Comment: But you can load the pre-compiled modules via `import`-function and then pass it to the Module "config data"?

Comment: Not if it's added after the build